# With Omniauth what callback params do you store in the db to allow for future app actions on behalf of the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, twitter-oauth, omniauth

I'm using omniauth with FB and Twitter.

My Authentications table as a UUID and ACCESS_TOKEN field. Should I be storing something else?

Twitter for example sends back a secret, and token. Do I need to store both those values?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't already, learn to love the Omniauth Schema: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema which defines all attributes available to you.

If you simply want people to be able to sign in using an external oauth provider, you don't need to store anything. What you choose to store depends on your application requirements. E.g., I allow users to sign in/up with an email/password, facebook, or linkedin. Once signed in, they can associate their account on my app with all of those profiles. For that reason, I want to store things locally. So, for example, a user can sign in with facebook, and I can mix in some attributes from their linkedin profile - as long as they have authenticated at least once using that account.

Comment: Can't find another appropriate place to ask this, so I will do it here. But has anyone created a sample rails migration to store ALL (why leave free data lying around) auth hash schema fields? I am just lazy to type it up at the moment, so if someone has done this already, it would be a good resource.